# Why map method is not getting called but setup and cleanup methods are getting called?

Tags: java, excel, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce Program which can process Delimited, Fixed Width and Excel Files. There is no problem in reading Delimited and Fixed Width File. But Problem with Excel File is setup() and cleanup() methods are getting called,but not the map(). I tried with adding annotations to map() still it didnt work.

```
public class RulesDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RulesDriver.class);

    RuleValidationService aWSS3Service = new RuleValidationService();
    HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    HashMap<String, String> controlMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String inputPath = "";
    public String outputPath = "";
    private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
    ControlFileReader ctrlReader = new ControlFileReader();
    CSVToExcel csv2Excel = new CSVToExcel();
    HashMap<Integer,String> countMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    HashMap<String,Integer> numberValueMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    HashMap<String,Object> rulesMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    CharsetConvertor charsetConvertor = new CharsetConvertor();
    ControlFileComparison controlFileComparison = new ControlFileComparison();
    boolean isControlFileValid = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new RulesDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("HADOOP MapReduce Driver started");
        if (args.length < 3) {
            LOGGER.info("Args ");
            return 1;
        }
        int j = -1;

        //Prop - Starts
        String cacheBucket = args[0];
        String s3accesskey = args[1];
        String s3accesspass = args[2];
        //Prop - ends
        // file2InputPath Value is from DB
        String file2InputLocation = "";
        String fileComparisonInd = "";
        String inputPath = "";
        String outputPath = "";
        String url = "";
        String userId = "";
        String password = "";
        String fileType = "";
        String ctrlCompResult = "N";


        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            //Prop - starts
            prop.setProperty("qatool.cacheBucket", cacheBucket);
            prop.setProperty("qatool.s3accesskey", s3accesskey);
            prop.setProperty("qatool.s3accesspass", s3accesspass);
            String propertiesFile = aWSS3Service.getObjectKey(cacheBucket, "application",prop);
            if(null==propertiesFile && "".equals(propertiesFile)){
                return 0;
            }
            S3Object s3Object = aWSS3Service.getObject(cacheBucket, propertiesFile, prop);
            LOGGER.info("Loading App properties");
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent());
            Properties appProperties = new Properties();
            try {
                appProperties.load(in);
                prop.putAll(appProperties);
                LOGGER.info(" ",prop);
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while reading properties file :" , e1);
                return 0;
            }

            initialize(prop);
            if (!(dataMap == null)) {
                if (("N").equals(dataMap.get("SuccessIndicator"))) {
                    return 0;
                }
                List value = (ArrayList) dataMap.get("LookUpValList");
                LOGGER.info("lookUpVallist",value);
            }
            if (dataMap != null) {
                controlMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataMap.get("ControlMap");
            }
            if (controlMap != null) {
                inputPath = (prop.getProperty("qatool.rulesInputLocation") + "/").concat((String) dataMap.get("InputFileName")); //TEMP
                LOGGER.info(inputPath);
                fileType = (String) dataMap.get("FileType");
            } else {
                inputPath = (prop.getProperty("qatool.rulesInputLocation") + "/").concat((String) dataMap.get("InputFileName"));
                LOGGER.info(inputPath);
                fileType = (String) dataMap.get("FileType");
            }
            rulesMap = (HashMap<String,Object>)dataMap.get("RulesMap");
            isControlFileValid = controlFileComparison.compareControlFile(controlMap, aWSS3Service, prop, rulesMap); //TEMP
            LOGGER.info("isControlFileValid in driver : "+isControlFileValid);
            if(isControlFileValid){
                ctrlCompResult = "Y";
            }
            conf.set("isControlFileValid", ctrlCompResult);
            // ** DATABASE Connection **/
            String ctrlFileId = controlMap.get("ControlFileIdentifier");
            url = prop.getProperty(QaToolRulesConstants.DB_URL);
            userId = prop.getProperty(QaToolRulesConstants.DB_USER_ID);
            password = prop.getProperty(QaToolRulesConstants.DB_USER_DET);
            InpflPrcsSumm inpflPrcsSumm = new InpflPrcsSumm();
            DBConnectivity dbConnectivity = new DBConnectivity(url, userId, password);
            inpflPrcsSumm = dbConnectivity.getPreviousFileDetail(ctrlFileId);
            dbConnectivity.closeConnection();
            LOGGER.info( " inpflPrcsSumm.getPrevFileId() " + inpflPrcsSumm.getPrevFileId());
            prop.setProperty(QaToolRulesConstants.PREV_FILE_ID, inpflPrcsSumm.getPrevFileId().toString());
            file2InputLocation = inpflPrcsSumm.getPrevFileLocation();
            boolean file2Available = file2InputLocation.isEmpty();
            String folderPath = "";
            String bucket = "";
            if (!file2Available) {
                String arr[] = file2InputLocation.split("/");
                if(file2InputLocation.startsWith("http")){
                    bucket = arr[3];
                }else{
                    bucket = arr[2];
                }
                folderPath = file2InputLocation.substring(file2InputLocation.lastIndexOf(bucket) + bucket.length() + 1, file2InputLocation.length());
            }
            // File 2 input path
            prop.setProperty("qatool.file2InputPath", file2InputLocation);
            if(!file2Available){
                file2InputLocation = file2InputLocation + "/Success";
                String file2Name = aWSS3Service.getObjectKey(bucket, folderPath,prop);
                LOGGER.info("bucket->"+bucket);
                LOGGER.info("folderPath->"+folderPath);
                file2Name = file2Name.substring(file2Name.lastIndexOf("/")+1, file2Name.length());
                prop.setProperty("file2Name", (null!=file2Name  && "".equals(file2Name))?"":file2Name);
                LOGGER.info(prop.getProperty("file2Name"));
            }
            prop.setProperty("qatool.auditPrevFolderPath", folderPath);
            prop.setProperty("qatool.auditBucketPrevFolderPath", bucket);
            LOGGER.info("ctrlFileId : " + ctrlFileId);
            LOGGER.info("BUCKET : " + bucket);
            LOGGER.info("folder : " + folderPath);
            Date dateobj = new Date();
            outputPath = (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.rulesOutputLocation") + "/" + dateFormat.format(dateobj); //TEMP
            fileComparisonInd = controlMap.get("FileComparisonIndicator");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String propSerilzation = gson.toJson(prop);
            conf.set("application.properties", propSerilzation);
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
            job.setJarByClass(RulesDriver.class);

            job.setJobName("Rule Validation and Comparison");
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesskey"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesspass"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesskey"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesspass"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesskey"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", (String) prop.getProperty("qatool.s3accesspass"));
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com");
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com");
            job.getConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com");


            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setReducerClass(RulesCountReducer.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            job.setMaxMapAttempts(1);
            job.setMaxReduceAttempts(1);

            if("UTF-16".equalsIgnoreCase(controlMap.get("FileCodePage"))){
                convertEncoding((String)dataMap.get("InputFileName"),rulesInputLocation,prop);
                if (!file2Available && "Y".equals(ctrlCompResult)) {
                    convertEncoding(inpflPrcsSumm.getPrevFileName(),file2InputLocation,prop);
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info("fileComparisonInd + "+ fileComparisonInd + " file2Available + " + file2Available + " ctrlCompResult + " + ctrlCompResult);
            if (fileType != null && fileType.equals(QaToolRulesConstants.INPUT_FILE_TYPE_DELIMI)) {
                job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(rulesInputLocation), TextInputFormat.class, TextRulesMapper.class);
                if (fileComparisonInd.equalsIgnoreCase(QaToolRulesConstants.FILE_COMP_INDICATOR) && !file2Available && "Y".equals(ctrlCompResult)) {
                    Path file2InputPath = new Path(file2InputLocation);
                    if (isInputPathAvail(file2InputPath, conf)) {
                        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, file2InputPath, TextInputFormat.class, TextRulesMapperFile2.class);
                    }
                }
            } else if (fileType != null && fileType.equals(QaToolRulesConstants.INPUT_FILE_TYPE_EXCEL)) {
                job.setInputFormatClass(ExcelInputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(rulesInputLocation), ExcelInputFormat.class, ExcelMapper.class);
                String inputFileName = controlMap.get("InputFileName");
                String fileExtn = inputFileName.substring(inputFileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                prop.setProperty("File", "Excel");
                prop.setProperty("fileExtension", fileExtn);
                if (fileComparisonInd.equalsIgnoreCase(QaToolRulesConstants.FILE_COMP_INDICATOR) && !file2Available && "Y".equals(ctrlCompResult)) {
                    Path file2InputPath = new Path(file2InputLocation);
                    if (isInputPathAvail(file2InputPath, conf)) {
                        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, file2InputPath, ExcelInputFormat.class, ExcelMapper2.class);
                    }
                }
            } else if (fileType != null && fileType.equals(QaToolRulesConstants.INPUT_FILE_TYPE_FIXED)) {
                prop.setProperty("File", "DAT");
                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(rulesInputLocation), TextInputFormat.class, FixedWidthMapper.class);
                if (fileComparisonInd.equalsIgnoreCase(QaToolRulesConstants.FILE_COMP_INDICATOR) && !file2Available && "Y".equals(ctrlCompResult)) {
                    Path file2InputPath = new Path(file2InputLocation);
                    if (isInputPathAvail(file2InputPath, conf)) {
                        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, file2InputPath, TextInputFormat.class, FixedWidthMapper2.class);
                    }
                }
            }
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "error", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "success", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, QaToolRulesConstants.ADDED_DELETED, TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class );
            /*MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, QaToolRulesConstants.ADDED_UPDATED, TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class );*/ //TEMP ADDED FOR ADDED AND UPDATED
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, QaToolRulesConstants.DETAIL, TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
            j = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
            LOGGER.info("Program Complted with return " + j);
            //Code Added for Control file Movement -- starts
            String outputBucket = rulesOutputLocation;
            outputBucket = outputBucket.substring(outputBucket.indexOf("//")+2, outputBucket.length());
            outputBucket = outputBucket.substring(0,(outputBucket.indexOf("/")));
            String controlFileNamekey = aWSS3Service.getObjectKey(outputBucket, "delivery/"+ dataMap.get("ControlFileName"),prop);
            if (controlFileNamekey != null) {
                controlFileNamekey = (String) controlFileNamekey.substring(controlFileNamekey.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,controlFileNamekey.length());
                String outputCtrlFilePath = "delivery/"+ dateFormat.format(dateobj) +"/" + controlFileNamekey;
                LOGGER.info("controlFileNamekey "+controlFileNamekey+"   outputCtrlFilePath "+outputCtrlFilePath);
                aWSS3Service.moveObjects(outputBucket, "delivery/"+controlFileNamekey, outputBucket, outputCtrlFilePath,prop);
            }
            //Code Added for Control file Movement -- Ends
            if (j == 0) {
                // Get counters
                LOGGER.info("Transfer");
                final Counters counters = job.getCounters();
                long duplicates = counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.DUPLICATES).getValue();
                LOGGER.info("duplicates->"+duplicates);
                long groupingThreshold = counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.GROUPING_ERR_THRESHOLD).getValue();
                LOGGER.info("groupingThreshold->"+groupingThreshold);
                if(groupingThreshold==1 || duplicates==1){
                    if(duplicates==1){
                        writeOutputFile(folderName,dateobj,"DuplicateRecords",prop,cacheBucket);
                    }else{
                        writeOutputFile(folderName,dateobj,"GroupingThreshold",prop,cacheBucket);
                    }
                }else{
                long successCount = counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.SUCCESS_COUNT).getValue();
                if (controlMap.get("ColumnHeaderPresentIndicator") != null
                        && controlMap.get("ColumnHeaderPresentIndicator").equals("Y")) {
                     successCount = successCount-1;
                }
                LOGGER.info("successCount "+successCount);
                LOGGER.info("TOLERANCEVALUE " + counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.TOLERANCEVALUE).getValue());
                LOGGER.info("RULES_ERRORTHRESHOLD " + counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.RULES_ERRORTHRESHOLD).getValue());
                long errorThreshold = counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.RULES_ERRORTHRESHOLD).getValue();
                LOGGER.info("COMPARISION_ERR_THRESHOLD " + counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.COMPARISION_ERR_THRESHOLD).getValue());

                writeOutputFile(folderName,dateobj, outputPath + "," + successCount + "," + counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.TOLERANCEVALUE).getValue() + "," + errorThreshold + ","
                        +counters.findCounter(MATCH_COUNTER.COMPARISION_ERR_THRESHOLD).getValue()+","+ctrlCompResult,prop,cacheBucket);
                String auditBucketName = "";
                auditBucketName = rulesOutputLocation;
                auditBucketName = auditBucketName.substring(auditBucketName.indexOf("//") + 2, auditBucketName.length() - 1);
                auditBucketName = auditBucketName.substring(0, (auditBucketName.indexOf("/")));
                String auditFileMovementPath = "delivery/" + dateFormat.format(dateobj);
                auditFile = auditFile.replace(".xlsx","");
                String inputFileName = (String) dataMap.get("InputFileName");
                inputFileName = inputFileName.substring(0,inputFileName.lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".xlsx");
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("Audit Bucket Name : " + auditBucketName);
                    LOGGER.info("Move parameter >>> outputbucketname  :  auditFileLocation : auditBucketName : auditFileMovementPath   auditFile ");
                    LOGGER.info("Move parameter " + outputbucketname + ", " + auditFileLocation + " , " + auditBucketName + " , " + auditFileMovementPath + "/" + auditFile + "_" + inputFileName);
                    aWSS3Service.moveObjects(outputbucketname, auditFileLocation, auditBucketName, auditFileMovementPath +"/"+ auditFile +"_"+ inputFileName, prop);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while moving audit file ",e);
                }
            }
            }else{
                writeOutputFile(folderName,dateobj,"DuplicateRecords",prop,cacheBucket);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in RulesDriver ", e);
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

Excel Mapper :

```
public class ExcelMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Inside Mapper Setup");
    }
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    }
    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
    InterruptedException {
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) => MINIMAL, you code here to not easily readable, all logger are not usefull and this is too compact and too huge for a forum ^^

Comment: Nothing is inside the map function. Try adding context.write() in the map method.

Comment: @azro I am testing this ! Hence i have lot of loggers here.  I just wanted to show the whole code. Thats why i placed it here.

Comment: @AmalGJose I have some validations inside map method. I also use context.write() in map() method. But still i face the problem. I have the same set of code executed for Fixed width and Delimited files. It is not working only for Excel file.